# При возврате назад сохранялось состояние на вкладке

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть переключалка с вложениями.
По умолчанию стоит active на первой вкладке.
Нужно чтобы при переходе на другую страницу и при возврате сохранялось значение вкладки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("tab1").style.display = "block";
    function openTab(evt, tabName) {
        var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
        tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
        for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
            tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
        for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
            tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
        evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    }



    for (j = 0; j < acc.length; j++) {
        acc[j].onclick = function(){      
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Вам эту вкладку нужно сохранять у клиента в куках

Comment: можно вообще без js это делать, якоря + `css:target` без поддержки старых ие

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать сохранять идентификатор вкладки в localStorage, то есть на onclick сделать localStorage.setItem(key_name, 'значение').

А при загрузке этой страницы брать значение localStorage.getItem(key_name), и если оно не undefined, то переключать на нужную (сохраненную) вкладку, а если undefined, то active будет на первой вкладке.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить вам как вариант хранить состояние как GET-параметр в ссылке, например www.вашсайт.info?active=1, а затем выбирать его таким образом

```
var url_string = window.location; 

url = new URL(url_string);
var c = url.searchParams.get("active");
console.log(c);
```